# Why does fetchColumn() always return 1?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, count

I am confused as to why this always, even when I know it should be 0, returns 1.

```
function check_user_data($username, $password) { 
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = $db->query($query);
    $results = $results->fetchColumn();
    echo count($results);
```

Comment: You should use **placeholders** instead of interpolating variables into query

Comment: because you are selecting a count in your query which returns a single number and then you are counting that single number with count($results)

Comment: @JaakKütt Post it as answer. Because nobody cares to delete *such* a question anyway.

Comment: aha thank you sir, that makes a lot of sense now

Comment: @user2554352 if you find an answer to solve your problem, try marking them as accepted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are selecting a count in your query which returns a single number and then you are counting that single number with `count($results)`

Answer (score 0):

> Why does fetchColumn() always return 1?

It doesn't.

Check your data and code.